# Can one use Vector4's in three.js geometry?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm currently getting to know the three.js library. The coordinates that are stored in a mesh's geometry are tuples (x,y,z). However, when doing affine transformations behind the scenes, the graphics card uses tuples (x,y,z,w) and encodes the transformations as 4x4-matrices.

> Can I store vertices explicitly as tuples (x,y,z,w) in three.js?

I don't want the value of w to always be 1. (Yes, this is a slightly strange request, and I'm fully aware that (x,y,z,w) can always be rescaled so as to make w=1. However, the application that I have in mind requires that I store my vertices as 4-tuples and that I can set all 4 coordinates.)

I don't feel like digging into raw WebGL if I can use three.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think* you should be able to just do this...

```
var positions = new THREE.Float32Attribute( triangles * 3, 4 );
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', positions );
```

`positions.array` will then be an array like `[ x, y, z, w, x, y, z, w, ... ]`

r67+